# Inflate layout saving theme

Tags: android

I wanna inflate layout to a view but also save theme that I have in my layout. **How can I do so?** I've tried this code but I did have any theme at all and moreover I had an error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
at com.example.amadey.myapplication5.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25)
```

This is my code:

```
@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    RelativeLayout mainLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main);
    RelativeLayout container = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.cont);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            ViewGroup view = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main,container, true);
    container.removeView(view);
    container.addView(view);
    //mainLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    >

    <TextView android:text="@string/hello_world" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Container.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/cont"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Wallpaper">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I think you're confused.  setContentView calls inflate for you.  What your code is doing is inflating a second copy of it and automatically adding it to container.  So the container.add isn't needed.  But there's also no reason to inflate it a second time, so whatever you really want to do this isn't it.

Comment: @gabe-sechan No, I want to inflate layout **saving theme** and then I want to add it to window manager.

Comment: Like I said-you're confused. I don't know what you're trying to do because that statement doesn't make sense. But what you're doing is just weird and wrong

Answer (score 1):

Just change this

```
ViewGroup view = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main,container, true);
```

to this

```
ViewGroup view = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main,container, false);
```

Here's [a great article](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/understanding-androids-layoutinflater-inflate/) on different scenarios when you would use `true` or `false` as a parameter for `attachToRoot`.

Comment: As I said I need inflate layout **AND SAVE THEME** an if I'll set attachToRoot to false I won't be able to save theme that I have